# Docusign-esign document font type and size (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have a document I create with html

```
const doc1 = new docusign.Document();
  doc1.documentBase64 = Buffer.from(htmlPage(args.htmlArgs)).toString('base64');
  doc1.name = args.documentName;
  doc1.fileExtension = 'html';
```

The htmlPage method just returns a html string.

I want to specify font type and size for the document.
I have been looking through docusign documentation.
How would I set the font type and size?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check / accept the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the font size and type inside the HTML page itself. The buffer that you just create, includes the payload for your HTML page - any configuration you want on that page, including font, should be set in that page.

You can refere to this example where the CSS is included in the header of the HTML doc.

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/eg002SigningViaEmail.js#L257

```
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: darkblue;margin-bottom: 0;">World Wide Corp</h1>
    <h2 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot you can do this in html.

Comment: It seems you need to specify font on individual items; specifying "<body style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;"> will not work.